# Python Json creating dictionary from a text file, printing file issue

Tags: json, windows, python-3.7

I was able to take a text file, read each line, create a dictionary per line, update(append) each line and store the json file.  The issue is when reading the json file it will not read correctly.  the error point to a storing file issue?

The text file looks like:

> 84.txt; Frankenstein, or the Modern Prometheus; Mary Wollstonecraft (Godwin) Shelley
>   98.txt; A Tale of Two Cities; Charles Dickens 
>   ...

```
import json
import re

path = "C:\\...\\data\\"

books = {}
books_json = {}
final_book_json ={}

file = open(path + 'books\\set_of_books.txt', 'r') 
json_list = file.readlines()
open(path + 'books\\books_json.json', 'w').close() # used to clean each test

json_create = []
i = 0

for line in json_list:
    line = line.replace('#', '')
    line = line.replace('.txt','')
    line = line.replace('\n','')
    line = line.split(';', 4)
    BookNumber = line[0]
    BookTitle = line[1]
    AuthorName = line[-1]
file
    if BookNumber == ' 2701': 
        BookNumber = line[0]
        BookTitle1 = line[1]
        BookTitle2 = line[2]
        AuthorName = line[3]
        BookTitle = BookTitle1 + ';' + BookTitle2 # needed to combine title into one to fit dict format
    books = json.dumps( {'AuthorName': AuthorName,  'BookNumber': BookNumber, 'BookTitle': BookTitle})
    books_json = json.loads(books)
    final_book_json.update(books_json)
    with open(path + 'books\\books_json.json', 'a'
             ) as out_put:                 
        json.dump(books_json, out_put)

with open(path + 'books\\books_json.json', 'r'
         ) as out_put:
'books\\books_json.json', 'r')]
    print(json.load(out_put))
```

> The reported error is: JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 133
>   (char 132)  - adding this is right between the first "}{".  Not sure
>   how json should look in a flat-file format? The output file as seen on
>   an editor looks like: {"AuthorName": " Mary Wollstonecraft (Godwin)
>   Shelley", "BookNumber": " 84", "BookTitle": " Frankenstein, or the
>   Modern Prometheus"}{"AuthorName": " Charles Dickens", "BookNumber": "
>   98", "BookTitle": " A Tale of Two Cities"}...

Comment: You need some commas between your braces    },{. But I would recommend writing all of the book data to a list of dictionaries and then using json.dumps() to convert it all at once.

Comment: Joshua, Thanks for the quick feedback. I did manual confirmation the addition of brackets and comma would allow the file to be read with a [...},{...].  Doing all book data at once will not work as the next assignment will be reading  x00K of items. I still need a means to be able to create a dictionary via reading the text file one line at a time and ending up with a final combine json file.

Answer (score 0):

> I ended up changing the approach and used pandas to read the text and then spliting the single-cell input.

```
    books = pd.read_csv(path + 'books\\set_of_books.txt', sep='\t', names =('r','t', 'a') )
    #print(books.head(10))

    # Function to clean the 'raw(r)' inoput data 
    def clean_line(cell):
...
        return cell

    books['r'] = books['r'].apply(clean_line)
    books = books['r'].str.split(';', expand=True)
```